# Boolean Full-Text Searches Mysql for keyword c++ and c#

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM candidate_details WHERE MATCH (primary_keyskill,secondary_keyskill)AGAINST ('"c#"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

and

```
 SELECT * FROM candidate_details WHERE MATCH (primary_keyskill,secondary_keyskill)AGAINST ('"c++"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

this two code give me result for 'c' not for c++ and c# how to manage it

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FULLTEXT search, by default, only works on words of four characters or more. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

When building FULLTEXT indexes, MySQL strips punctuation. So your `#` and `++` aren't searchable.

(Sad to say.)